Variable no almacena resultado
Tengo un programa de recepcion de producto(gas) me llega un documento con el numero de matricula del tren y cuantos galones tiene cargados y, lo convierto a litros y lo inserto en una DB de entradas de sql, al momento de descargar el producto en tiempo real se cuentan los litros que se obtuvieron realmente y se guarda en una DB Salidas, y en un Datagridview se pueden mostrar  la base de datos, el problema que tengo es que al momento de hacer una operacion de diferencia entre el valor del documento con el valor de llegada real, la variable que almacena el valor del documento me lo toma como 0, pero en la tabla de entradas si me hace la operacion de forma correcta. Alguna sugerencia??? Adjunto parte de mi codigo
                string matricula = txtbox_MatriculaCTQ.Text;
                string Idctq = verifica.ObtenerIDCarrotanque(matricula); //Se pasa la matrícula y se devuelve el ID del carrotanque
                bool dentro = verifica.ConsultarCTQEnEntrada(Idctq); //Se verifica si el ID de carrotanque ya se encuentra en la tabla de entradas
                float galones = verifica.ConsultaGalones(matricula); //consulta lo galones de la tabla carrotanques_transito
                double galon = 3.785; // valor para cinvertir galones a litros
                float litrosEntrada = (float)(galones * galon);   // se convierten galones a litros
                long peso = Convert.ToInt64(txtbox_PesoCTQ.Text);
                DateTime fechahoy = DateTime.Now;
                bool transito = verifica.ConsultarCTQEnTransito(matricula); //Se verifica si la matrícula aparece en la tabla carrotanques_transito
if (transito)  //Si el carrotanque está en la tabla de carrotanques_transito...
                {
                    verifica.CambiarTransito(matricula); //Cambia de 1 a 0 el bit del campo "Transito" en la tabla carrotanques_transito para saber que ya llegó
                    ctqporllegarDataGridView.Refresh(); //Luego se hace un refresh del datagridview ctqporllegar para que ya no aparezca esa matrícula
                }

                if (dentro) //Si el CTQ está adentro (en la tabla entradas) guarda como salida
                {
                    int registroDiario = SistemaBasculasIntersim.Properties.Settings.Default.regDiario; //Se toma el número del registro Diario,
                    decimal temperatura = SistemaBasculasIntersim.Properties.Settings.Default.temperatura; //la temperatura,
                    decimal presion = SistemaBasculasIntersim.Properties.Settings.Default.presion; //la presión,
                    decimal densidad = SistemaBasculasIntersim.Properties.Settings.Default.densidad; //y la densidad.
                   // float galones = verifica.ConsultaGalones(matricula);
                    string idEntradas = verifica.ConsultaIDEntradas(Idctq); //Se manda el Id del carrotanque correspondiente a la tabla carrotanques y retorna el id correspondiente en la tabla entradas
                    long pesobruto = verifica.ConsultaPesoBruto(Idctq); //Se consulta el peso bruto del carrotanque
                    long pesotara = peso; //Guarda el peso actual como peso tara
                    Formulas formula = new Formulas();
                    long pesoneto = formula.CalculaPesoNETO(pesobruto, pesotara); //Se pasa el pesobruto y el peso tara y se retorna el peso neto
                    float litrosneto = formula.CalculaLitrosNETO(pesoneto); //Se pasa el peso neto y se devuelven los litros
                    float diferenciaLts = formula.DiferenciaLts(litrosneto, litrosEntrada); // se hace la diferencia entre ltsEntrada y LtsNeto
                    bool salidaInsertada;
                    if (gasLP == 1) //Si el product
                                    //o es gasLP...
                        //Se pasan todos los datos para que se inserte la fila en la tabla de salidas, devulve true si se insertó correctamente y false en caso contrario
                        salidaInsertada = verifica.SalidaCTQ(Idctq, idEntradas, pesotara, pesoneto, fechahoy, 1, temperatura, presion, densidad, litrosneto, registroDiario, diferenciaLts);
                    else salidaInsertada = verifica.SalidaCTQ(Idctq, idEntradas, pesotara, pesoneto, fechahoy, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); //Si el producto es de grado alimenticio
                    string fechaentrada = verifica.ConsultaFechaEntrada(Idctq, idEntradas); //Se consulta la fecha de entrada en la tabla entradas
                    string fechasalida = verifica.ConsultaFechaSalida(Idctq, idEntradas); //Se consulta la fecha de salida en la tabla salidas
                    long pesotaramarcada = verifica.ConsultaTaraMarcada(matricula);
                    if (salidaInsertada) //Si se insertó correctamente la salida...
                    {
                        verifica.SacarCTQDeEntradas(Idctq); //Se saca el carrotanque de la tabla entradas, nada más se pone un 0 en el campo Dentro
                        txtbox_MatriculaCTQ.Text = "";  //se limpian los campos txtbox MatriculaCTQ, PesoCTQ y el label CTQDentroFuera
                        txtbox_PesoCTQ.Text = "";
                        lbl_CTQDentroFuera.Text = "-";
                        lbl_CTQDentroFuera.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        btn_Guardar.Enabled = false; //Se deshabilita el botón de Guardar
                        VentanaLectura_Load(sender, e); //Se carga nuevamente la Ventana Lectura para que se actualicen los datagridview

                        //Manda a Imprimir
                        //var impresion = new Impresora();
                        var impresion = new ImpresoraTM295();
                        if (rb_GasLP.Checked) //Si el producto es gas LP...
                        {
                            SistemaBasculasIntersim.Properties.Settings.Default.regDiario++; //Se aumenta el número de registro diario
                            SistemaBasculasIntersim.Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //Se guarda la configuración del programa
                            impresion.Imprimir(matricula, pesobruto, pesotara, pesoneto, (long)densidad, litrosneto, diferenciaLts, fechaentrada, fechasalida, idEntradas); //Se imprime el ticket de salida
                        }
                        else if (rb_GradoAlimenticio.Checked) //Si el producto es de grado alimenticio...
                        {
                            impresion.ImprimirSalidaGradoAlimenticio(matricula, pesobruto, pesotara, pesoneto, fechaentrada, fechasalida, idEntradas); //Se imprime el ticket
                        }
                    }
                }
                else //Si el CTQ no está dentro (en la tabla de entradas) lo guarda como entrada
                {
                    
                    long pesobruto = peso;
                    //
                    //Formulas formula = new Formulas();
                   // float litrosEntrada = formula.LitrosEntrada(galones, galon);
                    bool entradaInsertada = verifica.EntradaCTQ(Idctq, pesobruto, fechahoy, 1, gasLP, litrosEntrada); //Se guardan los datos en la tabla Entradas´´


Las preguntas de este tipo deben ir acompañas de un [MCVE], el cual es un código MINIMO y que reproduzca el error tal cual como tú lo has descrito.
